# Deleting a file can not be restored

Tags: c#

As a means of c # when you delete a file, fill zeros clusters on which the file was written

Can this be done by means of c #?

p.s. without a full format

Comment: Well you could fill it full of zeros, then delete it...

Comment: If you want to make the file even harder to restore, you can call `SetLength(0)` one a `FileStream` which will make the file have 0 bytes in size, then before you delete it you also give it a name of random characters/letters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code regarding BugFinder's comment. The method overwrites the file data with 4KB zero byte blocks.

```
public static class FileHelper
    {
        public static void EraseFile(string fileName)
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
            var zeroBuffer = new byte[4096];
            using (var file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                while (file.Position < fileInfo.Length)
                {
                    var bytesToWrite = (int)Math.Min(4096, fileInfo.Length - file.Position);
                    file.Write(zeroBuffer, 0, bytesToWrite);
                }
                file.Flush(true);
            }
            File.Delete(fileName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think `ShredFile` would be a more suitable name for the method, as this is actually a simple way of shredding it.